# Avoid leaving devices used

Tags: r, error-handling, pdf-generation

I want to write on a pdf through a function.

```
pdf("termolayout.pdf")
generate_termolayout(db) 
   #This functions prints thermolayouts, but when the db is corrupted, generates errors
dev.off()
```

How do I ensure R runs `dev.off()` even when `generate_termolayout` fails?

Comment: have a look at `tryCatch()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `on.exit`:

```
mypdf <- function() {
  pdf("termolayout.pdf")
  on.exit(dev.off())
  stop("An error.")
}

mypdf()
#Error in mypdf() : An error.
dev.cur()
#RStudioGD 
#2
```